# How can I trace if WhisperPush in Cyanogenmod 11 is working?

Tags: android, cyanogenmod

I recently installed Cyanogenmod 11 Pepper on my Xperia sola phone. Happily, CM 11 natively supports Short and Media Message Service encryption. I found this very convenient.

Because of this reason I immediatly registered in WhisperPush (pre-installed app with CM11). It all went fine and I got my TextSecure verfication code via SMS.

**1. Do I have to do additional steps after receiving that TextSecure verification code?**

I tried to text my gf who's using TextSecure but she could not initiate a encrypted session with me. If she tries to do so, I receive the key but nothing more.

**2. How I can verify from within the CM "Messaging" App if encryption is working? (is there a flag of something)**

Thx in advance and all the best,

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"2. How I can verify from within the CM "Messaging" App if encryption is working? (is there a flag of something)"

I believe that there is currently no way of telling whether the message is encrypted or not and this is something that the devs are working on. IMHO this is terrible for a system that boast high security.

Comment: That's what I found out after doing some research. I think it will be included in future updates. Thanks!